# Xcode won't open, quit unexpectedly

Tags: xcode

Each time I try to open xcode I get this error:[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. I right clicked Xcode and selected show contents. Then if you go into Contents/Plugins and delete everything there...and the restore from the trash it started working again.